# Angular add class to element inside existing Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out the best way to add a function to the existing ng-click function below that will add a class to the element upon execution.

```
 $ctrl.next = function(id) {
    $state.go('individual', {id : id}, {reload : true});
     ga.track({
        action:'Button click',
        label:'Navigation Button Right',
        category:'Button'
    });

  }
```

Basically this function triggers a state change to the next item in an array that comes from a database and tracks the element clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a sample, I am not 100% clear on what you have. This [plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/JMKrRbdI3bjpfOqPy77T?p=preview) shows clicking a button, and changing it's class to make it blue.

**JS**

```
app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
  $scope.clickFunction = function(evt) {
   angular.element(evt.srcElement).addClass('clicked-button');
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
  <div ng-controller='ctrl'>
    <button ng-click="clickFunction($event)">Click Me</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ah, So I have a ng-click setup in my routes that triggers a function to track the button. With my controller as $ctrl I basically wanted to try and be smart and work out away to have another function run inside my $ctrl.next() so that it just adds ".class" to the element i have ng-click="ctrl.next()" on